# What should be the regular expression which matches exactly one $ (dollar) followed by any number of digits?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
$ : match results $
$637 : match results $637
$$ : match results $
$272$ : match results $272
$262$$ : match results $272
$$445: match results $
3727 : match results null
2727$: match results null
```

Comment: I don't see any code that you have tried. Could you tell us what you have done so far and what you're stuck on?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: Hi Mike. I want to replace all the characters from a string except $ followed by any digit. String should contain $26272 I.e [Dollar][digit] format only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$` is a special character that represents the end of the string.

Escaping the dollar symbol should solve your problem:

```
^\$\d*
```